# Getting SendTransactionError

Tags: spl-token, metaplex, metadata

I'm getting "SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Program failed to complete" Where did i go wrong?

```
const tokenMetadata = {
    name: name,
    symbol: symbol,
    uri: uri,
    sellerFeeBasisPoints: 0,
    creators: null,
    collection: null,
    uses: null,
  } as DataV2

  // transaction to create metadata account
  const transaction = new web3.Transaction().add(
    createCreateMetadataAccountV3Instruction(
      {
        metadata: metadataPDA,
        mint: mint,
        mintAuthority: user.publicKey,
        payer: user.publicKey,
        updateAuthority: user.publicKey,
      },
      {
        createMetadataAccountArgsV3: {
          data: tokenMetadata,
          isMutable: true,
          collectionDetails: null
        },
      }
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

Few things to check (Usually better to turn off preflight check to see the actual error from the block explorer)

1. Check the `symbol` isn't too long
2. Check the transaction is not too large (long URLs cause this)
3. Ensure MetadataPDA is correct
4. Ensure you set `recentBlockhash` & `payer` params on the `transaction`

Data structure all looks correct from the code you have posted

Here is a full example of creating a NFT:

```
import {web3} from "@project-serum/anchor";
import {createCreateMasterEditionV3Instruction, createCreateMetadataAccountV3Instruction, PROGRAM_ID} from "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata";
import {
    createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction,
    createInitializeMintInstruction,
    createMintToInstruction,
    getAssociatedTokenAddressSync,
    MINT_SIZE,
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
} from "@solana/spl-token";

async function getCreateNFTTransaction(owner: web3.PublicKey, connection: web3.Connection): web3.Transaction {
    const nftMint = web3.Keypair.generate()
    const tokenMint = nftMint.publicKey
    const [metadataPDA] = web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync([Buffer.from("metadata"), PROGRAM_ID.toBuffer(), tokenMint.toBuffer()], PROGRAM_ID)

    const mintLamports = await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(MINT_SIZE);

    const ata = getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(tokenMint, owner, false, TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID)


    const [nftMasterEdition] = web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync([Buffer.from("metadata"), PROGRAM_ID.toBuffer(), nftMint.publicKey.toBuffer(), Buffer.from("edition")],
        PROGRAM_ID)

    const ON_CHAIN_METADATA = {
        name: "{NAME}",
        symbol: "{SYMBOL}",
        uri: "{URI}",
        sellerFeeBasisPoints: 0,
        uses: null,
        creators: [],
        collection: null,
    };

    const txn = new web3.Transaction().add(
        web3.SystemProgram.createAccount({
            fromPubkey: owner,
            newAccountPubkey: tokenMint,
            space: MINT_SIZE,
            lamports: mintLamports,
            programId: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        }),
    );

    txn.add(createInitializeMintInstruction(tokenMint, 0, owner, owner, TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID),
        createCreateMetadataAccountV3Instruction({
            metadata: metadataPDA,
            mint: tokenMint,
            mintAuthority: owner,
            payer: owner,
            updateAuthority: owner,
        }, {
            createMetadataAccountArgsV3:
                {
                    data: ON_CHAIN_METADATA,
                    isMutable: false,
                    collectionDetails: null
                }
        }, PROGRAM_ID),
        createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(owner, ata, owner, tokenMint, TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID),
    )

    txn.add(createMintToInstruction(tokenMint, ata, owner, 1n, [], TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID))


    //Used to create a master collection
    // txn.add(createSetAndVerifyCollectionInstruction({
    //  metadata: metadataPDA,
    //  collectionAuthority: owner,
    //  payer: owner,
    //  updateAuthority: owner,
    //  collectionMint: collectionMint,
    //  collection: collectionMetadata,
    //  collectionMasterEditionAccount: collectionMasterEdition,
    //  collectionAuthorityRecord: collectionAuthority,
    // }))


    txn.add(createCreateMasterEditionV3Instruction({
        edition: nftMasterEdition,
        mint: nftMint.publicKey,
        updateAuthority: owner,
        mintAuthority: owner,
        payer: owner,
        metadata: metadataPDA,
        tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    }, {createMasterEditionArgs: {maxSupply: 0}}))

    const bhash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash("confirmed")
    txn.feePayer = owner
    txn.recentBlockhash = bhash.blockhash
    return txn
}
```

Comment: I added a try catch statement and debugged the code to find out the issue is with this code:

```try {
    // send transaction
    const transactionSignature = await web3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(
      connection,
      transaction,
      [user]
    );

    console.log(
      `Create Metadata Account: https://explorer.solana.com/tx/${transactionSignature}?cluster=devnet`
    )
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error: ", error);
  }```

@Cloakd

Comment: The error that I'm getting:
**Error:  SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Program failed to complete**

Comment: Have you created the mint & metadata PDA?

Comment: I figured it out myself. I used a different method. Thanks a lot for your help though. Cheers

Comment: For future reference, `Program failed to complete` means that the on-chain program panicked / crashed during execution. This could happen for a few reasons: a bug in the program, running out of VM compute units, etc